# How to Paste as Comment in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, macros

This is a micro optimization that I'd have in my ideal IDE - the ability to paste from the clipboard directly into the editor as a comment.  The idea is sometimes I feel like I lose entire seconds to moving my hand over to the mouse, selecting what I just pasted, having involentary stress over trying to beat the red-squiggly's from appearing, and finally pressing control-K,C.

Comment: Which VS version are you using?

Comment: +1 for nice question, lol I have never think about that. But now, I really need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type `/*`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, type `*/`.  Your hands never need to leave the keyboard.

Answer (score 11):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but if you paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (Cycle through the Clipboard Ring), the pasted text is already highlighted and selected for you. You can then follow that up with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> to comment it out.

Answer (score 3):

Try [SmartPaster](http://inedo.com/downloads/smart-paster), it's a visual studio 2005, 2008 and 2010 addon which adds paste as comment, string, stringbuilder and region to the right click menu.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to record a macro to do this.  In Vs you can use the record macro functionality, you can create your own button in the menu to activate the macro.